# Is there a function call happening when we index an object such as a list or tuple ?

Tags: python

This is probably a silly question but I was wondering, when we have a container object such as a list or a tuple, and we index it:

```
l = [2,4,5,6]
l[0]
```

in the console we get:

```
out[#]: 2
```

much in the same way we would get if we did:

```
def ret(num):
    return num
ret(1)
```

Is there a hidden function call being made when we index lists or tuples or the like?

Comment: `__get__` iirc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Python has certain ["magic methods"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) which are called from objects using the corresponding operator(s). The subscript operator(`[]`) is one of them. The magic method is called [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). The documentation for `__getitem__()` provides more information:

> Called to implement evaluation of `self[key]`. For sequence types, the accepted keys should be integers and slice objects. Note that the special interpretation of negative indexes (if the class wishes to emulate a sequence type) is up to the `__getitem__()` method. If key is of an inappropriate type, `TypeError` may be raised; if of a value outside the set of indexes for the sequence (after any special interpretation of negative values), `IndexError` should be raised. For mapping types, if key is missing (not in the container), `KeyError` should be raised.

You can observe how `__getitem__()` works by calling it manually:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst.__getitem__(0)
1
>>> lst.__getitem__(1)
2
>>> lst.__getitem__(2)
3
>>> # etc...
```

There are several other methods similar to `__getitem__()`;[`__setitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) and [`__delitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__). `__setitem__()` sets the given index in the list to a given value. The syntactic sugar for calling the method is `sequence[index] = value`. On the other hand, `__delitem__()` deletes the value at the given index. It's syntactic sugar is `del sequence[index]`. Both methods can be called manually and observed:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst.__setitem__(0, 10)
>>> lst.__getitem__(0)
10
>>> lst.__delitem__(0)
>>> lst.__getitem__(0)
2
>>>
```

**Resources**

- [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/). [Section 3.3 *Special method names*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; pretty all operations on objects map to special methods. In this case it is the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method.